# Encoding in imap_search PHP

Tags: php, encoding

When I try to search latin symbols or digits - all right. But when I try to find cyrillic symbols - I found wrong data. I found to set encodung as argument like this

```
imap_search($inbox,'TEXT "кириллица"',SE_FREE,"utf-8");
```

but it doesnt works too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write UTF-8 instead of utf-8?